# May the word "Blue", when refering to musical genre, be used in the singular?

Tags: word-in-context

For instance: may a singer say...

> Now I'm gonna sing a **blue** I wrote twenty years ago.

Or should he say...

> Now I'm gonna sing a **blues** I wrote twenty years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is correct; you should say "sing a blues song". But not "sing a blue song" - that might not be understood as referring to the musical genre at all.

Strictly speaking, sometimes the singular "blue" is used in this way; the Merriam-Webster dictionary records a meaning of "blue": "of, relating to, or used in blues" and gives a specific example of "a blue song". But this is a rare, possibly obsolete form. It's better to use only the plural form to refer to the genre.

Comment: Not so: *a blues* is quite common. For corroboration Google "played a blues in E" or something similar.